# Mongo db won't connect with my code or write to the database

Tags: discord.py

This is my code and I'm trying to get it so when a user does the add command, it stores their id and number they have used the command, but this isn't working, please can someone help.

```
num = 0

@client.command()
async def add(ctx):
    global num
    num += 1
    
    await ctx.send('non')
    mongo_url = "mongodb+=true&w=majority"
    cluster = MongoClient(mongo_url)
    db = cluster["mongo_url "]
    collection = db["mongo_url "]

    ping_cm = {"bank":num}
    collection.insert_one(ping_cm)
```

Comment: Have you provided your mongo_URL properly?

Comment: No thats all it is, I dont know what is wrong

Comment: It wouldn’t work as you haven’t provided your private information to connect with your database, plus you have some other issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your mongo_url token is incorrect, it should have your name and password and db that you are storing it to, but you are accessing your token currently instead of your bank name, whatever that is called,

for example,

```
    db = cluster["mongo_url "] #This has been set to your token, your mongo_url which won't do anything
```

You have used "bank" in other parts of your code, which is really confusing but I assume thats what you want to do and access, this will then store it in different rows for each user id who uses the command

```
num = 0

@client.command()
async def add(ctx):
    global num
    num += 1
    
    await ctx.send('non')
    mongo_url = "YOUR_MONGO_DATABASE_URL"
    cluster = MongoClient(mongo_url)
    db = cluster["bank"]
    collection = db["bank"]

    ping_cm = {"bank":num}
    collection.insert_one(ping_cm)

    await ctx.channel.send("Bank Updated!")
```

Make sure you are providing your mongo url "properly" otherwise the code won't be working at all they should look like this: eg.
EXAMPLE ONLY

```
    mongo_url = "mongodb+srv://name:password@bank.9999000.mongodb.net/bank?retryWrites=true&w=majority" #EXAMPLE
```

You can get the URL when you go to the database you want to connect to, the click manage > db_url and copy that where I have included “YOUR_MONGO_DATABASE_URL" that should work if it is correct